# Android - External Storage Issue

Tags: android, android-external-storage

I have small app written in android.

With AsyncTask I'm trying to download images from server and store them on external or internal storage on my phone.

The images are in format jpg, png etc.

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... param)
{
    try
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < param.length; i++)
        {
            String src = "http://myLINK/images/"+param[i];
            URL url = new URL(src);

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.connect();

            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            images.add(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input));

            if (images.get(i) != null){
                saveImageToExternalStorage(images.get(i), param[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException io_exception){
        Log.e("ERROR", io_exception.getMessage());
    }

    return "success";
}



// save image to external storage
private void saveImageToExternalStorage(Bitmap image, String image_name)
{
    try
    {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        String path;

        // check if external storage exists
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state))
            path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        else
            path = Environment.getDataDirectory().toString();

        OutputStream fOut;

        File file = new File(path, "myDIR/images/"+image_name);
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

There error is:

`/storage/emulated/0/myDIR/images/57d7fa462860b_image1.jpeg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Do you request the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in the manifest? Do you request the permission at runtime? Also, you cannot write to `Environment.getDataDirectory()`, so you need to change that (e.g., `getFilesDir()` on a `Context`).

Comment: Have you set permissions in the manifest: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> and for writing: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> already set.

Comment: @CommonsWare at runtime i do not request permissions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it

Comment: @CommonsWare in manifest file I have set the permissions.

Comment: CommonsWare is referring to API 23 and above for targetSDKVersion as mentioned in the link.

Comment: Can you tell me what to change in my code?